# Will grep go faster with line breaks?

Tags: grep, performance

I have some big files that I have changed into "standardized form", removing line breaks. I want to speed up greps on those files. I know that you can optimize grep by doing `grep 'partofpattern' | grep -E 'partofpattern [[:digit:]]+'` -- that is, have grep search for lines that contain a more simple part of a pattern and then have grep run a second time on the few lines that contain part of the pattern. That makes me think that grep somehow works line-by-line. So will adding line breaks to big files with no line breaks speed up grep?

Comment: If a file has *no* line breaks, your `grep` commands either print the entire file or nothing at all. I think something must be missing from the description of what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @MichaelHomer I am using the -o option

Comment: I think `grep` and `sed` parse intermittently gulping by line break. If you remove all the line breaks, it may well be faster; but I'd worry about buffer overflow.

Comment: I'm skeptical that you can actually speed grep up by scanning lines twice. Do you have an actual benchmark which demonstrates this?

Comment: It depends strongly on the pattern. If it's a regular expression that does a ton of backtracking, shorter lines should help a lot. For a static string it should just be a matter of memory usage.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably just use `fmt` or `fold` or `pr` or one of those. Here's `fmt`:

```
until [ $((i=i+1)) -gt 10000 ]
do  printf %s\  words and more words
done | fmt
```

#### OUTPUT

```
words and more words words and more words words and more words words
and more words words and more words words and more words words and more
words words and more words words and more words words and more words
words and more words words and more words words and more words words
and more words words and more words words and more words words and more
#...and so on for a long time
```

`grep`'s buffer is bound to give way under any serious load unless it can dump it at a newline boundary.

For example:

```
time (
    tr \\0 \\n < /dev/zero | 
    sed 'c words and words and words and words and words and' | 
    tr -d \\n | 
    grep -o words
)
grep: memory exhausted
49.42s user 44.93s system 229% cpu 41.070 total
```

It takes a while - but it's got a lot of empty RAM on this system, and still managed to go bust in under a minute.

So just:

```
fmt <file | grep search
```

More robustly though, if there is some reliable single character string delimiter in the file:

```
tr ${delim} \\n <file | grep search
```

Answer (score 2):

grep definitely works line based, as does sed. It won't necessarily speed up searching, but producing the output for a matching line should be quicker.

Comment: I just added in line breaks every 1000 char and it speeded it up like WHOA sed -e "s/.\{1000\}/&\n/g" < temp.txt